# STM32 How to turn on a LED a certain period of time

Tags: timer, stm32, interrupt

Like described in the title i want to turn on a LED for a period of time.

The time must be able to be interrupted. For example triggered by a button or touch display. I tought of using a timer with the interrupt but i have no idea how to realize it.

Does someone have example code for this problem? Would be nice.

Comment: what did you try so far? We are not voo-doo coding service https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_programming

Comment: Time to read a book ? https://consense.com.ua/en/lib/book/Noviello-Mastering_STM32 it's all in there, have fun :) pssst.. it's page 320